# Reading csv like file to pandas

Tags: excel, pandas, export-to-csv

I am trying to read an Excel file into `pandas`, but I get the message `format and extension of the file don't match`.

When I try to use `read_excel`, I get an error message, I am therefore using `read_csv`.

This is where the issue is; my 'Excel like' file has empty cells on some rows, and it creates a weird df, where some field are shifted:

[image: Image 1]

My code is below:

```
2010 = pd.read_csv(r'{0}\\file.xls'.format(path_temp),sep = 
r'\t*',encoding='iso-8859-2')
```

In the output, column `Outcome` appears in 6th (date 4) column of the data frame from row 8. Would you know of a workaround? I need to load this file automatically every 15mins, meaning I d like to avoid a manual open and save as with excel

Comment: Can you post an example file? What is the error message when you open it using `read_excel`?

Comment: It says unsupported format or corrupt file. Expected BOF etc...

Comment: What does it look like if you open it in a text editor?

Comment: You can find an example if you scroll to the bottom and download any of the zip file : http://clients.rte-france.com/lang/fr/visiteurs/vie/prod/indisponibilites.jsp

Comment: With a text editor, the file starts with "ID..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your separator is a regex. `sep=r'\t*'` matches any number of consecutive tabs, and so what should be blank cells get treated as a single delimiter. Try `sep='\t'` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, that does work for the empty cells ! I

Comment: I know have the issues that some cells contain quotes with a serie of ---- inside. Despite using the quotechar = ' " ' parameters, those ---- do create a line break.
here is my code : pd.read_csv(r'{0}\\DonneesIndisponibilitesProduction_2017.xls'.format(path_temp),delimiter=r'\t',encoding='iso-8859-2',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, quotechar = '"')
Am I missing something ?