# tabulation separated file into pandas

Tags: regex, csv, pandas

Good afternoon,

Following my question here [Reading csv like file to pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204770/reading-csv-like-file-to-pandas), I have another one that prooves a bit more tricky.

The excel spreasheet I am trying to read is separated by tabulatiobn, and has a column with quotes. I am trying to use the quotechar parameter to avoid an unexpected column, but it does not seem to work as the separator is a regex

My code is below, if that helps:

umm2017=pd.read_csv(r'{0}\DonneesIndisponibilitesProduction_2017.xls'.format(path_temp),sep = r"\t",encoding='iso-8859-2', quotechar = "'")
umm2017 = umm2017.drop(umm2017.index[len(umm2017) - 1])
umm2017.to_csv(r'{}\umm_rte_2017.csv'.format(path_output), index = 'False')

and the excel I am trying to read with pandas is here

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBfi0.png)

And the file I am trying to parse can be found here, at the bottom https://clients.rte-france.com/lang/fr/visiteurs/vie/prod/indisponibilites.jsp

EDIT : spent the afternoon trying to understand; so it seems quotchar is not supported with the C engine, which is the only one I can use as my file uses regex as sep. I tried to deleted all hyphens from the original file, but it does not work.

here is the output csv I get; with some extra rows messing things up :
[image]

Many thanks

Comment: How does it look in the python console? If it appears alright there, the issue is probably with writing it. What happens if you add `sep=r'\t'` to `to_csv`?

Comment: I do have the same issue in the console, where there are weird rows in the dataframe, and even adding the separator to the 'to_csv' function does not work. 
I wonder if it comes from the original file itself, whenre I open it with notepad++ I see the extra rows already.
Got the feeling there is no solution to this issue  !

Comment: Realized I'd picked a file from your link that happened to not exhibit the issue. Switched to another and was able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, to avoid the issue with `pd.read_csv` interpreting separators over one character in length as regexes and causing trouble with quoting, you could replace `\t` with another character first, then feed that to `pd.read_csv`.

For example, with the 2014 file from your link, `;` seemed to work:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
with open(fileloc, encoding='iso-8859-2') as file:
    data = file.read().replace('\t', ';')
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=';').to_csv(newfileloc, encoding='iso-8859-2', index=False)
```